# Error with Weblogic 10.x while deploying

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am receiving an error while I try to connect my local environment to a Test DB. Deployment of the ear file fails.

## Here's the exception stack trace.

```
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:22 PM IST> <Info> <Deployer> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1378381942855> <BEA-149060> <Module nemo of application NeMo successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:24 PM IST> <Warning> <JMSPool> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1378381944212> <BEA-169808> <There was an error while making the initial connection to the JMS resource named jms/statisticsFactory from the EJB "JMSWriter" inside application "NeMo". The server will attempt the connection again later. The error was javax.jms.JMSException: [JMSPool:169803]JNDI lookup of the JMS connection factory jms/statisticsFactory failed: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.statisticsFactory' didn't find subcontext 'jms'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jms/statisticsFactory'> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:26 PM IST> <Info> <Kodo> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185> <> <1378381946428> <BEA-2004002> <Starting BEA Kodo 4.1.3.1> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:26 PM IST> <Info> <Kodo JDBC> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185> <> <1378381946474> <BEA-2002382> <[JDBC] Using dictionary class "com.bmw.nemo.business.util.MyOracleDictionary".> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:26 PM IST> <Info> <Kodo JDBC> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185> <> <1378381946584> <BEA-2002360> <[JDBC] OpenJPA is now connecting to the database in order to figure out what JDBC driver you are using, as OpenJPA must alter its behavior for this database depending on the driver vendor. To avoid this connection, set the DriverVendor value in your org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary configuration property to one of the following values: oracle, oracle92 (for the 9.2 driver), datadirect, datadirect61 (for driver versions <= 3.1), other For example: org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary: oracle(DriverVendor=oracle92)> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:28 PM IST> <Warning> <Kodo> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185> <> <1378381948783> <BEA-2000012> <[MetaData] Found duplicate query "XXXX.ProjektByWerkJoin" in "class XXXX.ProjektBE". Ignoring.> 
####<Sep 5, 2013 5:22:59 PM IST> <Info> <EJB> <H1-DDM67BS> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185> <> <1378381979251> <BEA-010051> <EJB Exception occurred during invocation from home: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessEJBHomeImpl@239c1e7 threw exception: <1.0.0.1.1 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds 
BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
<1.0.0.1.1 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 32 seconds 
BEA1-00003CA049AA50DAD185]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:3849)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:3813)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.handleCheckedException(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:40)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:987)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:796)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:766)
    at kodo.kernel.KodoQuery.execute(KodoQuery.java:43)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:762)
    at kodo.kernel.KodoQuery.execute(KodoQuery.java:39)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:517)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:269)
```

===============

- I have tried all sorts of setting on JTA by increasing the timeouts etc on weblogic console, didn't work.
- I have dumped the whole data on my local oracle DB and then connected it works perfectly but it's a tedious job again and again to take the dump from remote DB and dump it on my local DB.
- I am not sure why it's not working when I connect to remote DB but locally it works with the same weblogic settings.

Please share your opinions.

-Vishal Nadikudi

Comment: Presume that remote DB is not blocking the request to connect or firewall is not blocking the request.

Comment: I am able to connect to the remote DB from SQL clients like SQL developer, so I don't think it is an issue with firewall ?, any other suggestions please?

Comment: Was there some exception in this transaction?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, the transaction is always timed out as you can see in the above exception. JTA settings in Weblogic didn't work, the result of these exceptions is that the application never loads.